# How can I output the summary statistics without a group by variable?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In `python` `panda`, how can I output summary statistics into a dataframe without a group by variable?

This is my dataset "Table1":

```
    email         Total_Orders    Amount
    a@gmail.com   5               150
    b@gmail.com    
    c@gmail.com   4               69
    d@gmail.com   2               30
```

My desired output is:

```
   num_emails  total_purchasers  total_orders   total amount
   4           3                 11              249
```

If I have a "group by" variable, this is what I'd do -

```
    Table2 = DataFrame(Table1.groupby(['category']).agg({'emails': 'count', 'total_orders': 'count', 'total_orders': np.sum, 'Amount': np.sum})).reset_index()
```

but I don't have a group by variable, and so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `groupby()`, as you've observed, because there is no key. Instead, just aggregate everything:

```
pd.DataFrame({'num_emails':[Table1.email.count()],
              'total_purchasers':[Table1.Total_Orders.count()],
              'total_orders':[np.sum(Table1.Total_Orders)],
              'total_amount':[np.sum(Table1.Amount)]})
```

Here's the result:

```
   num_emails  total_amount  total_orders  total_purchasers
0           4           249            11                 3
```